# Strange visualization/print 'lobstr' package

Tags: r

I ran the sample code but I get a rather strange visualization

```
library("lobstr") 

ast(a + b + c)
o-`+` 
+-o-`+` 
| +-a 
| \-b 
\-c
```

But judging by the example from [here](https://www.tidyverse.org/blog/2018/12/lobstr/), I should get a different result

```
ast(a + b + c)
#> █─`+` 
#> ├─█─`+` 
#> │ ├─a 
#> │ └─b 
#> └─c
```

**What's wrong?**

```
sessionInfo()



R version 4.3.0 (2023-04-21 ucrt)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows 7 x64 (build 7601) Service Pack 1

Matrix products: default


time zone: Europe/Kiev
tzcode source: internal

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] lobstr_1.1.2

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] compiler_4.3.0    cli_3.6.1         tools_4.3.0       rstudioapi_0.15.0
[5] crayon_1.5.2      rlang_1.1.1
```

===================
update for  Roland

```
unclass(ast(a + b + c))

[1] "\033[38;5;214mo\033[39m-\033[1m\033[35m`+`\033[39m\033[22m"  
[2] "+-\033[38;5;214mo\033[39m-\033[1m\033[35m`+`\033[39m\033[22m"
[3] "| +-\033[1m\033[35ma\033[39m\033[22m"                        
[4] "| \\-\033[1m\033[35mb\033[39m\033[22m"                       
[5] "\\-\033[1m\033[35mc\033[39m\033[22m"
```

===================
update Here is the  output of this function that you asked for `l10n_info()`

```
    $MBCS
    [1] FALSE
    
    $`UTF-8`
    [1] FALSE
    
    $`Latin-1`
    [1] FALSE
    
    $codepage
    [1] 1251
    
    $system.codepage
    [1] 1251
```

Comment: I get the expected result. Can you please show the result of `unclass(ast(a + b + c))`?

Comment: Your problem is probably that you are not using a UTF-8 locale (I guess you are using a cyrillic locale). What is the output of `l10n_info()`? The source code of `lobstr:::box_chars` shows that lobstr switches the layout depending on options and the locale

Comment: OK, so that's the explanation and nothing is wrong. You need to switch to a different locale if you want to reproduce the example output.

Comment: @Roland or set `options(lobstr.fancy.tree = TRUE)` if you don't want to go to the lengths of changing locale.

Comment: @AllanCameron Thanks. I was too lazy to test if that actually works. I assumed the package authors had a reason to switch this off for non-utf8 locales.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set the `lobstr.fancy.tree` option rather than changing your locale:

```r
lobstr::ast(a + b + c)
o-`+` 
+-o-`+` 
| +-a 
| \-b 
\-c 

options(lobstr.fancy.tree = TRUE)

lobstr::ast(a + b + c)
█─`+` 
├─█─`+` 
│ ├─a 
│ └─b 
└─c
```

Answer (score 1):

In order for [all examples](https://www.tidyverse.org/blog/2018/12/lobstr/) to be displayed `fancy`, and not just `ast()`, i need to change the locale

```
Sys.setlocale("LC_ALL", "en_US.UTF-8")
```